# Outlook 2013 - div width

Tags: html, css, ms-office

Simple code:

```
<div class='container' style='width:600px;'></div>
```

When I check email in litmus.com - mso 2013 ignore width, div is 100% width on mso 2007, 2010, 2013 client.

In this div I have

```
<table width='100%'></table>
```

Is there some know bug with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email clients each render mail differently.

Look at [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) page to see what you can and cannot send in each major email client

If you are hand coding an email template its really trial and error. Outlook just happens to be the worst of all of the email clients.

Comment: Yes I know. 2007,2010 and 2013 look bad. I know this site and I also use litmus.com where I have info that in 2013 outlook width is unsupported :) I don't believe it , div must have a width, but outlook just ignore it...

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps you should turn to a tool like [Zurb Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) which works pretty well on most e-mail programs (still handles Outlook the worst, but it's better)

Comment: heh..it's true... outlook 2007-2013 doesn't support width for DIV and P :) what a s...

Comment: I just remembered, What you need to do is set EVERYTHING in a table. Have tables within tables if you need to. Thats how you get it to work correctly.

Comment: Yes I do it like that, but i Try to make some container div. Right now  I put if statement only for mos and create new table as constainer(becauser table width is supported) for whole email - and it works.